# Bootstrap example nav bar abnormal on my machine

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, notepad++

I copied exactly the same code from official example `http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html`.

But on my machine something add 20px more to the space between navbar and content. I uploaded the pic.

[image]

I tried to change it to `body { padding-top:40px; }` and it's ok on pc, but the 20px appears again on mobile. So I cannot find out why. Please help me with that.

Edit: you can see my page on http://sheldon.sinaapp.com/stackoverflow

**THE REAL REASON!!!**

Some editor on Windows will add `BOM` to the start of file. It's invisible and used to notice the editor that it is utf-8 encoded.

For more details of `BOM`, see [Byte Order Mark(wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

In notepad++, you can use `Encoding -> Encode in utf-8 without BOM`.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page so we can compare?

Comment: @DaveR I deployed it to http://sheldon.sinaapp.com/stackoverflow. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - I've worked out the problem.  You have a line of whitespace before your `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.  If you delete this line and move `<!DOCTYPE html>` to line 1, you'll be working fine!

I've managed to recreate the problem here:

Version with whitespace (http://jsfiddle.net/TW9JP/)

Version without whitespace (http://jsfiddle.net/z8DQB/)

Comment: I don't have that line now on `http://sheldon.sinaapp.com/stackoverflow`. But still not fixed. The `"    "` below body still there

Comment: There is still one space!  You need to have absolutely no characters before the doctype.

Comment: where did you see the space. in chrome view source?

Comment: what are you using to prepare your html files?  because it seems there is some weird encoding stuff going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Oh man . . . I'm running out of suggestions! - try downloading this from pastebin http://pastebin.com/jfVNKSSU rename the file extension to .html and upload to your server!

Comment: It's ALL RIGHT now! see `http://sheldon.sinaapp.com/stackoverflow` Magic touch. I think I have to look into my editors. Thx!